# Assign cell hyperlink to button via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We're talking about the same spreadsheet here, no cross-links. I just want a button to jump to another part of the same spreadsheet. None of the scripts I found online do this, they all open the link in a new window where you have to sign in into Google again and give an untitled project (presumably the script) permission to edit spreadsheets. Using =Hyperlink doesn't look very nice because you have to hover over the link and then click the little window that appears.

I hope a script like that exists, or if anyone knows how to solve this with macros or add-ons I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

This function jumps to the last column in the same row.  Run the showDialog() function to display the sidebar and the button is on the top of the sidebar.

```
function jump() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var max=sh.getMaxColumns();
  var offset=max-col;
  rg.offset(0, offset).activate();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="Jump" onClick="jump();" />';
  html+='<script>function jump(){google.script.run.jump();}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that will create a menu ("Actions") [1] on your spreadsheet UI with an option "Go to Cell" that when clicked it will run the activateCell function that will activate the cell you choose as a parameter on the getRange function [2].

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Go to Cell', 'activateCell')
  .addToUi();  
}

function activateCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("Z40").activate();  //Change the cell to whichever you want
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range